Неправильный порядок воспроизведения плейлиста m3u ffmpeg
создал m3u плейлист для дальнейшего стриминга с ffmpeg
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:10,video1.mp4
/path/to/your/files/video1.mp4
#EXTINF:100,video2.mp4
/path/to/your/files/video2.mp4
#EXTINF:100,video3.mp4
/path/to/your/files/video3.mp4
#EXTINF:100,video4.mp4
/path/to/your/files/video4.mp4

в самом плейлисте значительно больше треков, но проблема заключается в том, что плейлист воспроизводит всегда последние 4 трека из данного списка.
для понимания того,что предыдущие записи в плейлисте валидны, я удалил последние 4 трека.
Если бы записи были не валидными, то ffmpeg их пропустил,но он стал воспроизводить последние 4 файла(значит записи правильные).
что я пробовал:

создавал по новому плейлист.
параметр -ss для установки времени старта воспроизведения
добавил #EXT-X-VERSION:3,#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:1,#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0 под шапку плейлиста
гуглил и терроризировал ии. похожих проблем я практически не нашел

параметры запуска ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -f hls  -ss 01:50:00 -i playlist.m3u -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -report -f flv rtmps:/
